# Id token and access token and user info

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal

I use angular for the front end and spring boot for the backend

Backend need to know the authenticated user.

It seem to have an id token and access token. User role access would be managed by spring boot app.

I need to user id, user email... to search db to get role.

I read backend end should not use id token, but i think it's only the id token who provided user info?

Edit

example in a online accounting application, when user get bill xyz, i need to be sure is the owner of this bill... to want to return bill of another client. that way it's important to know the user connected

Comment: Where did you read "backend end should not use id token"? If your roles are defined in a database against a user id, and your userid is currently only available at front end then there is _no other way_ to check roles then to send the user id to the back end. So I suggest you simply create an API that takes userid as input and returns roles as output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use msal in the frontend.

Then make the call to the backend with the token.

The token contains the user email address. You can read the email address from the token in the backend.

Comment: You're right - No need to send the userid to the back end. Just send the token as that contains everything.